# GCC compilation on Azure using a GUI

Tags: gcc, azure, centos, azure-vm-role, compiler-as-a-service

As a part of a college project we are implementing Compiler as a Service. For this we are planning to use a Virtual Machine on Azure preferably Ubuntu or CentOS. The problem is we have no leads. How do you get the GCC compiler onto the VM in the cloud, and how do we move forward with the UI? Is there a way by which the programs if input in the UI, can be executed by the compiler on the cloud?

Comment: Why would you need GUI? Why can't you do something like ideone.com?

Comment: Yes exactly. We want to do something exactly like that. But we were thinking that designing it on Visual Studio would be better. Excuse our lack of knowledge. We are new to this. Previously been working on SQL Azure only. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Getting GCC into the cloud VM is as easy as doing it on a local machine.

For ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

GUI's are harder. The Eclipse GUI will work great on a local machine, but can't easily be used on a cloud server.

Actually, that's not true: it'll work fine with SSH X11 forwarding (`ssh -X <server>`), but the performance will suck unless you're very close to the cloud datacenter.

There are two work-arounds:

1. Set up a VNC server.
2. Set up an NX proxy server.

Both are good in their own way, but I'd suggest the VNC setup will be easier.

Comment: Sir, we are very new to this. We have previously worked only on SQL Azure actually. 
We wanted to know is it possible to create an application on Visual Studio who's backend could be connected to the Virtual Machine. Somewhat like those online compilers. 
Installed GCC on Ubuntu. Thank you.
We used it using PuTTY. Our next aim is to create that UI on Visual Studio so that it can be deployed as an application. 
One of the Users here said that we could do something like ideone.com and yes, I think that's what we need. Just Cloud Based. How to go about it?

Comment: Well, of course, you can certainly write any program you like in Visual Studio, so I suppose the question is how to interact with the server. I presume you'd like it to be secure and encrypted? That means you need either SSH or SSL. Id set up a web-server like nginx or Apace on the cloud server, with a self-signed SSL certificate, and then use libcurl in the client to talk to it. Then, I'd write a small server app (tornado works well) to interpret the client requests, to the work, and return the results.

Comment: Really, though, if you want more details, try something out first, and then post more specific questions.